# How to set '0' value to the end while sorting

Tags: php, sql

I trying to sort My table value in "asc" order, well i have used following code to get result, but Result i get is in form of 0,01,02.. i want it to be as 01,02..
how do i do it..i had used some function for joining tables..

```
$where_array = array('publications.status =' => 1);
$orderby = $this->db->order_by("uv_nirf", "ASC");
$data['universities'] = $this->common_model->pub_seo_join('vm_universities','','uv_id',$where_array,$orderby);
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY your_field = 0, your_field;`

Comment: well how can i use it in Code igniter ..??

Comment: You can use `$this->db->query($sql)` , `$sql` is your query string

Comment: @JigarShah yes it work too..ty..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only need to change ur order_by to following code..

```
$where_array = array('publications.status =' => 1);
$orderby = $this->db->order_by("uv_nirf = 0,uv_nirf");
$data['universities'] = $this->common_model->pub_seo_join('vm_universities','','uv_id',$where_array,$orderby);
```

check if this will work..